# Centering histogram bars over axis values

Tags: histograms, plotting, alignment

I'd like to center the bars in my histograms over the correct values of the x-axis.

Here is a simplified example:

[image: simplified example]

The most common value in the dataset is zero, but glancing at the histogram this isn't apparent. It might be zero, or it might be one. This histogram also makes one wonder if the number three appears in the dataset (and it doesn't).

Here's a photoshop mockup of what I'd like (for the same dataset input)

[image: desired output]

Kind thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Histogram[{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2}, {1},  Ticks -> {{# + .5, #} & /@ Range[-1, 3], Automatic}]
```

[image]

**Update 1:** More generally, *without hard-coding the range of values*, you can use `HistogramList` as follows:

```
data = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2};
bspec = {1};
Histogram[data, bspec, 
   Ticks -> {{# + .5, #} & /@ HistogramList[data, bspec][[1]],  Automatic}]
(* same picture *)
```

**Update 2:** You can also use a combination of  `HistogramList` and `BarChart`:

```
hl = HistogramList[data, bspec];
BarChart[hl[[2]], ChartLabels -> Placed[hl[[1]], Below]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's cute. Is is possible to do it without hard-coding the range of values? `Ticks->Automatic` works nicely when I happen to have a dataset that doesn't lie within `[0,2]`. (Some of my datasets are in [0,140000] for instance)

Comment: @Harold, please see the update.

Comment: Wow! Perfect. If only I could upvote you more than once. Warm regards.