# Why are these two histograms plotting so differently?

Tags: histograms, ticks

I have two lists, which are pretty similar. They are given by:

```
list1=Flatten[Table[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{1, 2},{2, 9},{3, 3},{4,73},{5, 38}}]
list2=Flatten[Table[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{1, 2},{2, 10},{3, 8},{4,65},{5, 22}}]
```

ie. list1 is a list of 2 1's, 9 2's, 3 3's, etc.

If I plot a histogram of them next to each other they come out like this:

```
{Histogram[list1],Histogram[list2]}
```

[image]

And I can't figure out why the labelling is different. I would like to have all of my numbers in the centre of the column, so tried using the answer from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69487/centering-histogram-bars-over-axis-values). as so:

```
{Histogram[list1, 
  Ticks -> {{# + .5, #} & /@ HistogramList[list1][[1]], Automatic}], 
 Histogram[list2, 
  Ticks -> {{# + .5, #} & /@ HistogramList[list2][[1]], Automatic}]}
```

But that comes out like this:

[image]

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: The definitions for the lists can be shortened to `list1 == Flatten[Table @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 9}, {3, 3}, {4, 73}, {5, 38}}]` and `list2 = Flatten[Table @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 10}, {3, 8}, {4, 65}, {5, 22}}]`

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This in Mac version 12.1.0.0 using the input provided.

Comment: I'm using 12.0.0.0. Could it be a version issue?

Comment: @JonathanShock Try `{Histogram[list1, {1}], Histogram[list2, {1}]}`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi that's it, thank you!

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, Any idea why it is giving different results without that?

Comment: @JonathanShock I can reproduce the difference on 12.0.0.0. `HistogramList`, which is what `Histogram` uses to compute the bin delimiters and counts, generates different output on 12.0.0.0 for `list1`. Guess it is a bug that was fixed in 12.1.0.0.

Comment: Interesting that 12.0 and 12.1 are different. Good idea with the extra argument to Histogram. Scales look better same as with `{Histogram[list1, {1}, PlotRange -> {0, 70}], 
 Histogram[list2, {1}, PlotRange -> {0, 70}]}'